# Entity Beans in the jmx-console?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jmx, entity-bean

Is it possible to view entity beans with the jmx-console? If so, how?

Comment: What do you mean by "entity beans"?  EJB 2.x entities?  JPA entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EJB 2 EntityBeans can be viewed in JMX console (iirc) JPA (EJB 3) Entities (note, those are not called Entity Beans) can not be viewed directly.

It is possible thought to expose the JPA entities indirectly via the underlying Hibernate Session when enabling Hibernate statistics.